# Iterating through the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: python, iteration, sequences

so i'd like to iterate through the Fibonacci sequence (but this could apply to any non-arithmetic sequence). i've written a function fibonacci:

```
from math import sqrt
def F(n):
    return ((1+sqrt(5))**n-(1-sqrt(5))**n)/(2**n*sqrt(5))
```

which returns the fibonacci number for any given input. this bit seems to work OK. However, I'd like to include a couple of conditions, like even numbers and F(n) below a certain limit. I tried using an if loop like this:

```
def ser():
    count = 0
    for i in F(n):
        if F(n) <= 4000000 and F(n) % 2 == 0:
            count = count + F(n)
```

But it seems like you can't use F(n) in the iteration for loop like I did. I'm a complete novice at python, so how would be best to use the F(n) function I created to iterate over the sequence? Thanks

Comment: What is `F(n)`? It is not defined.

Comment: I don't see that you created a `F()` function.  You created a `fibonacci()` function.

Comment: If your `F(n)` function returns an integer just change loop to `for i in xrange(F(n))` and it will work.

Comment: sorry, F(n) is the fibonacci function from the beginning, I just changed the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the range of `n` that you are looking to run the fibonacci number on?
Your definition of fibonacci is in a closed form, so you need to give each number you want to calculate:

```
import itertools
count = 0
for n in itertools.count(1):
    if F(n) > 4000000:
        break
    if F(n) % 2 == 0:
        count += F(n)
```

You can use a generator form of fibonacci and use `itertools.takewhile()` to limit the output:

```
def F():
    a,b = 0,1
    yield b
    while True:
        a, b = b, a + b
        yield b

count = sum(f for f in it.takewhile(lambda x: x <= 4000000, F()) if f % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: OK, so I want n as F(n) < 1000, for example, so that all of the Fibonacci numbers which are less than 1000 and are odd, for instance, or end in 7.

Comment: This would set the maximum of the input to F(n) not the value of F(n).

Comment: Ok, understand your question more - you need to have a break in your loop... see update.

Comment: For 64 bit unsigned integers, max n for Fibonacci(n) is 93, Fibonacci(93) = 12200160415121876738.